# In SQLite, how do I get the first key, next key and previous key?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm a newb at SQL and SQLite.  Since SQLite doesn't seem to support TOP, what syntax would I use to select...

- the row with the first primary key? (in key order)
- the row after the row with a certain key?
- the row prior to the row with a certain key?

Comment: Hint:  SQLite supports `limit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite supports [LIMIT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), so selecting the "first" isn't a problem.

> The LIMIT clause is used to place an upper bound on the number of rows returned by a SELECT statement.

Of course you'll need to use ORDER BY as well.

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.

Comment: I think that solves the problem of finding the first key and the next key after any particular key.

But how do I find the row with the key that is previous to a particular key?

Comment: @MikeatBookup Change the filter predicate and direction of ordering. The approach the same. However, if this is an assignment, perhaps LIMIT is not to be used at all?